# extract string from cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a situation like this in excel 2007:

.15X.04-1.25X.625-SD+str

.15X.04-1.25X1.25-SD

.15X.04-1.5X1.25-SD

.15X.04-1.75X1.75-SC

.15X.04-1X.625-SD+str

.15X.04-2.25X2.25-SC

.15X.04-2.5X2.5-SC

.15X.04-2.75X2.75-SC

.15X.04-2X1.75-SC

.15X.04-3X3-SC

.15X.06-1.25X.625-SD+str

.
.
.
.

I need to extract the number between "-" and "X", OR the whole part ,like this: -1X; -1.25X; -1.5X; -1.75X and so on .

how can i do it?

Comment: cant use MID , Cuz left part will be changed rundomly. I want to search "-" and "X" , then grab the number in between. help plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell you're trying to get the data from were in cell `A1`, this formula would do it:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1),FIND("X",A1,FIND("-",A1))-FIND("-",A1)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Private Function GetValue(ByVal cellLocation As String) As String

    Dim txt As String
    txt = Application.Range(cellLocation).text

    Dim split As String
    split = split(txt, "-")(0)

    Dim result As String
    result = split(partOne, "X")(0)

    GetValue = result

End Function
```

Comment: sorry, may i ask how to use this code? it doesnot look like the code i can put into cell. I m a newbeee.....

Comment: @Blitzcrank try the other answer then)

Comment: Sorry this was assuming you were comfortable with VBA, @JohnBustos' answer below will help  you out!